# Generate ABC00 instead of [ABC00] with bibtex alpha style

Tags: bibtex

I use `bibtex` with `alpha` being my preferred style. I would like to be able to generate citations without square brackets. That is, `\cite` generates *[ABC00]*, but I just want *ABC00*. Is there an easy command to generate this?

Answer (score 2):

In the default format the square brackets in cite come from

```
\def\@cite#1#2{[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}
```

so you can use

```
\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}}
\makeatother
```

but beware many classes and packages redefine the citation macros so the details may depend on the details of your document that you have not mentioned.